# How to render number as us currency without any decimal point in Ext JS 4.1

Tags: extjs

I am using following code to render number as currency

```
UtilFormat.currency(v, '$', 0);
```

I don't want any decimal point in output for example  input (1279039) then output should be $1,279,039 but i am getting $1,279,039.00

Thanks.

Comment: So write a custom function to strip off the last 3 characters.

Answer (score 2):

There is no global object UtilFormat in ExtJS 4.1. Try

```
Ext.util.Format.currency(1279039, '$', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
var val = Ext.util.Format.number(value , '0,000') 
return '$' + val;
```